# Why does my CSS Grid not start from Column one?

Tags: html, css, sass, css-grid

Recently I have started learning CSS Grid. I am currently working on a landing-page section that consists of 6 rows and 9 columns. I have two elements that should fill out this section.

**What have I tried to fix the issue:**

I googled the issue and read about functionality such as "3 / span 2" to choose a starting position.
I tried the grid-column-start method, starting from Auto, 0 and 1.

My HTML

```
<div class="landing-page">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="landing-page-item image">Image</div>
        <div class="landing-page-item text">Text Here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My SCSS

```
.landing-page {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background: rgb(2,0,36);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
    box-shadow: 0 12px 21px #7889b6;
    
    .container {
        padding-top: 100px;
        display: grid;
        height: 100%;
        grid-template-rows: repeat(6, 1fr);
        grid-template-columns: repeat(9, 1fr);
        grid-column-start: 1;
    }
}

.landing-page-item {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    
    &.image {
        grid-row: span 4;
        grid-column: span 2;
        background-color: green;
    }
    
    &.text {
        grid-row: span 4;
        grid-column: span 6;
        background-color: red;
    }
}
```

**What I expected to happen:**

Image start at the most top-left grid and fills out 2 columns and 4 rows.
Text starts right next to the Image and fills out 6 columns and 4 rows.

**What actually happens:**
[image: The grid does not function as expected.]

The image fills out two columns to display the error in a clearer way. What have I done wrong?

Comment: your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/rabzjmq6/

Comment: @TemaniAfif based on your comment I looked at what outside sources could interfere with it. It turns out that clearfix.less:14 added a css attribute: content: " "; This is seemingly done to provide a Clearfix. I renamed my container to main-content and the issue was solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at what outside sources could interfere with it. It turns out that clearfix.less:14 added a css attribute: content: " "; This is seemingly done to provide a Clearfix. I renamed my container to main-content and the issue was solved.